# Python: Using a list with TF-IDF

Tags: python, pandas, text, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have the following piece of code that currently compares all the words in the 'Tokens' with each respective document in the 'df'. Is there any way I would be able to compare a predefined list of words with the documents instead of the 'Tokens'.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None)  

list_contents =[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    list_contents.append(' '.join(row.Tokens))

# list_contents = df.Content.values

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(list_contents)
df_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(),columns= [tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()])
df_tfidf.head(10)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @stackyflowy123, welcome to SO!  Thanks for putting some of your code here.  Can you maybe give us an example of what you're trying to do and how it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to make the Vectorizer consider a fixed list of words, you can use the `vocabulary` parameter.

```
my_words = ["foo","bar","baz"]

# set the vocabulary parameter with your list of words
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    norm=None,
    vocabulary=my_words)  

list_contents =[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    list_contents.append(' '.join(row.Tokens))

# this matrix will have only 3 columns because we have forced
# the vectorizer to use just the words foo bar and baz
# so it'll ignore all other words in the documents.
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(list_contents)
```